# Eclipse frequently hangs (with 100% CPU usage on a single core) after ivyDE resolve

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse frequently hangs forever after ivyDE resolve consuming 100% CPU on a single core, i need to kill it on windows task manager, restart and ivyDE resolve again (hoping it doesnt hangs again)
Im running Eclipse on Windows 7. Java: version 1.8.0_25 with -clean -vmargs -Xmx4g -Xms750m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

thread dump:

```
    2015-12-10 11:44:34
    Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

    "Worker-384" #3588 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000044c5d000 nid=0x1d14 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000005e13f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.nextJob(JobManager.java:980)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c07e1d78> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.startJob(JobManager.java:1488)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Worker-383" #3587 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000044c5c000 nid=0x1ce8 runnable [0x0000000058b2e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalJob.addLast(InternalJob.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.nextJob(JobManager.java:1003)
        - locked <0x00000006c07e1d78> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.startJob(JobManager.java:1488)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Worker-382" #3586 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002587e800 nid=0x1f9c waiting for monitor entry [0x000000005e38e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.sleepHint(JobManager.java:1277)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c07e1d78> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Worker-380" #3584 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000026609000 nid=0x8d0 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000005d1fe000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.nextJob(JobManager.java:980)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c07e1d78> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.startJob(JobManager.java:1488)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "RMI TCP Connection(9)-10.5.1.189" #3566 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000030b4e000 nid=0x126c runnable [0x000000005d07e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000007732ad870> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007ad6b9d20> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

    "Worker-365" #3565 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000030b4c800 nid=0x15d4 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000005ea8e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.sleepHint(JobManager.java:1277)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c07e1d78> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "RMI TCP Accept-0" #3558 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000044c5b800 nid=0x1b20 runnable [0x00000000520ee000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000007acf45198> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None


    "JavaScript indexing" #163 daemon prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x00000000253b7000 nid=0x2e4 in Object.wait() [0x000000003990f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:370)
        - locked <0x00000006c90e7e08> (a org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "qtp1870832419-100 Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:55716" #100 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e3d000 nid=0x1f00 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000003933f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c8e01668> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:938)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "qtp1870832419-99 Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:55716" #99 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e39000 nid=0x18b4 runnable [0x000000003918e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000006c8e01668> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:938)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "qtp1870832419-98 Selector1" #98 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e39800 nid=0x19d4 runnable [0x000000003904e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000006c8df5d90> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006c8df5d80> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006c8df5c20> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "qtp1870832419-97 Selector0" #97 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e33000 nid=0x1184 runnable [0x0000000038ede000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000006c8df21d0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000006c8df21c0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000006c8df2050> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Java indexing" #39 daemon prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x0000000020e3d800 nid=0x11b0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000026e0e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:382)
        - locked <0x00000006c48de448> (a org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e35000 nid=0x1998 in Object.wait() [0x0000000027a5e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:106)
        - locked <0x00000006c2dda518> (a org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "EMF Reference Cleaner" #29 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e36800 nid=0x1f40 in Object.wait() [0x0000000026c4e000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000006c09ec738> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.CommonUtil$1ReferenceClearingQueuePollingThread.run(CommonUtil.java:70)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Provisioning Event Dispatcher" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020e32000 nid=0x1a24 in Object.wait() [0x000000002199f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
        - locked <0x00000006c1bb9808> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Worker-JM" #22 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000208bc000 nid=0x1814 in Object.wait() [0x00000000240ef000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalWorker.run(InternalWorker.java:58)
        - locked <0x00000006c1848598> (a java.util.ArrayList)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Bundle File Closer" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020892000 nid=0x14b8 in Object.wait() [0x0000000021baf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
        - locked <0x00000006c1bb9a98> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Start Level Event Dispatcher" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001f79b800 nid=0x1ebc in Object.wait() [0x0000000021a9f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
        - locked <0x00000006c083e070> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Framework Event Dispatcher" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001f743000 nid=0x1628 in Object.wait() [0x00000000217ff000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
        - locked <0x00000006c1bb9d98> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d5ad000 nid=0x191c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "C1 CompilerThread3" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d545000 nid=0x1acc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "C2 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d532800 nid=0x624 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d52a800 nid=0x19bc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d525800 nid=0x1db4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d521000 nid=0x1cf0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d520000 nid=0x1910 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001c46c000 nid=0x1f28 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e8df000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000006c1caf248> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c463000 nid=0x11f8 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e54f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000006c1b8d738> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

    "main" #1 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000001ed8000 nid=0xdf8 waiting for monitor entry [0x00000000020ad000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.isIdle(JobManager.java:800)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c07e1d78> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEIdleHelper$1.run(IDEIdleHelper.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runTimer(Display.java:4271)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.messageProc(Display.java:3358)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

    Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

Comment: Which Eclipse version/build? Have you tried to update to the latest?

Comment: Im using Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

i don´t update to newer versions due to formatter issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I was able to resolve by changing memory allocation to Eclipse during startup. I suggest use one of the below approach.

Option 1: Edit eclipse.ini and change following parameters. Increase this values based on the RAM memory available on your system

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Also check or review plugins installed which are of no use to you and can be removed. This can help to increase the performance(Will reduce the memory used by Eclipe).

Option 2: I found Mar version of Eclipse to be little slower. Use Kepler or LUNA version which are much more stable.

Comment: Im using eclipse Kepler with  -Xmx4g -Xms750m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m